# applying master page on layout pages

Tags: master-page

I am applying my custom master page on application layout pages which I am deploying using Visual Studio. My issue is I have to copy my custom master page in the same directory where my layout pages exist otherwise it's not working.

I want to deploy my custom master in the default master page directory and refer it to my layout pages.

Is it possible? Or do I have to copy my custom master page in the layout page directory?

Answer (score 1):

Deploy Master Page through visual studio with adding module template
Add your custom master page in module

In the Modules Element.xml File(This will deploy your master in to _catalogs/masterpage)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="MasterPage" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" RootWebOnly="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <File Path="MasterPages\CustomMasterPage.master" Url="CustomMasterPage.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary"/>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Set Master Page through code

```
using (SPWeb currentWeb = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent)
            {
                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    Uri masterUri = new Uri("Path of custom master page");
                    currentWeb.MasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
                    currentWeb.CustomMasterUrl = masterUri.AbsolutePath;
                    currentWeb.Update();
                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            }
```

Please refer [this link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/SharePoint-2010-Developing-0b4d7af6)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your master to the "Masterpages" library at `_catalogs/masterpage`.

And in your application pages you set the `DynamicMasterPageFile` property to `~masterurl/your_masterpage_name_here.master` and then it should work.